# Generating a Youtube embed iframe from URL in a form for preview

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

So I am creating a form where people can input all sorts of data describing a recipe. One of those data types is a youtube video URL. I want to take the data the user puts into the URL box and generate an iframe with the video so that can preview and make sure it's the right one. This is the code I am using:

```js
function makeVideoPreview(aTable, aTextBox)
{
 var aVideo = document.createElement("iframe");
 aVideo.setAttribute("width", "560");
 aVideo.setAttribute("height", "315");
 var theURL = aTextBox.value;

 var idIndex = theURL.indexOf("v=") + 2;
 var vidID = theURL.slice(idIndex, theURL.length     );;

 var embedLink = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ vidID;
 aVideo.setAttribute("src", embedLink);
 aVideo.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', 'true');
    aVideo.setAttribute('frameborder', "0");
 aTable.appendChild(aVideo);
}
```

If I use the debugger and step through the code, the iframe gets placed in the right place, begins to load, and then I get a 405 method not allowed error and it reloads the entire page.

If I copy the generated iframe from the debugger and paste it into the html source, it works fine. What in the world is going on?

I'm not a web guy. I mostly do native iOS development, but I am making this as a resource so that the company I am making the app for can add recipe content. I'm sure it is something I just don't understand about the platform.

thanks.

Comment: How is this function called, via the submit event of a form or similar? Sounds like you did not properly prevent the default submission process, so that a POST request is made to a "static" URL (such as an HTML file, webservers are usually configured to reject that.) If those hints are of no help, please create a [mcve].

Comment: Youtube offer a player API, maybe using that would be more suitable? [Youtube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: Provided code worked without any problems on isolation ....

Comment: @CBroe the form is dynamically created. In this instance there is a table with 1 row and initially 2 columns. One with a text field, one with a “preview button”. The preview button onclick attribute calls the posted code. Maybe I do not understand how to “prevent the default submission process” I assumed that only happened when a submit is pressed. How might one go about preventing the POST from a button click?

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer! I think. Apparently every element “button” defaults to submit. I assumed that submit was a submit and button was an action less element unless given a specific onclick or similar function. Apparently one must set the button type to be button or it defaults to submit.